# Send transaction with smart contract

Tags: solidity, metamask

is it possible to send transactions to an address from the smart contract without having to confirm the transaction on metamask?
I mean, I need a certain condition to start a transaction that sends coins to a wallet, but I can't make it automatic without my confirmation.

is it possible to do what i ask?
Thank you

ps i am using js and web3

Comment: A contract by itself cannot send a transaction. It is always an external owned account (EOA - not a contract) that initiates a transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.

**First thing: import IERC20 smart contract in your contract**

1. You declare the address: `address public toSend;`
2. You approve the address to spend tokens using approve function:

> ```
> function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
>                 _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
>                 return true;
>         
>         }
> ```

and call it like that:

```
approve(toSend, amount);
```

3. Send the tokens using transfer function

   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
   _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
   return true;
   }

you will call it `transfer(toSend, amount)`

P.s. If you want ot do that from a web interface please check ether.js documentation

Comment: sorry but i couldn't find a way to make it work via web3

Comment: The author specifically asked "without my confirmation". Anything you do with browser wallets requires a confirmation. This would only be possible with backend wallets, but your answer doesn't reflect that at all.